# Generating data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, generator

I wrote a function, **generate supply**, which generates the delivery of some product to the store.That is, the function works by creating a text file with two columns: the day of the month (or week, decade) and the value of the product, using a random number generator so that the values of the products on different days are different. Function parameters: file name, location, maximum and minimum value,number of days. The problem is that I use this function to create data for deliveries and sales to the store, and my sales exceed deliveries. I tried to configure it somehow through the maximum and minimum parameters, but it didn't work. How could I solve this problem?
Here is code:

```
generate.supply<-  function(way='',
                            file.name='Supply',
                            days=7,
                            min=100,
                            max=140,
                            goods='Milk, packaging'){

  #creating a table from a single column with a length of days
  tabl<-data.frame('Day'=1:days)
  #use the colnames()function to create a column header
  #adding columns for each product
  for(i in 1:length(goods)){
    tabl[i+1]<-sample(x=min[i]:max[i], size = days)
    colnames(x=tabl)[i+1]=goods[i]
  }
 #write this table to a file with the extension txt
  write.table(
    x=tabl,
    file= paste0(way,file.name),
    col.names = TRUE,
    row.names = FALSE
  )
 return(tabl) 
}
generate.supply(way = "", file.name= 'Shop1_in_K',days=7,goods = c('Cottage cheese, pcs','Kefir, pcs', 'Sour cream, pcs'),min=c(85,100,110),max=c(110,120,130))# generating delivery
generate.supply(way = "", file.name= 'Shop1_out_K',days=7,goods = c('Cottage cheese, pcs','Kefir, pcs', 'Sour cream, pcs'),min=c(85,100,110),max=c(105,119,125))# generating sales
```

Comment: How about using the max-value of deliveries as input for max-value sales?

Comment: You mean here :                                                                                 
`generate.supply(way = "", file.name= 'Shop1_out_K',days=7,goods = c('Cottage cheese, pcs','Kefir, pcs', 'Sour cream, pcs'),min=c(85,100,110),**max=c(110,120,130)**)?`

Comment: If that's what you meant, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick and ugly solution. You function has to know the maximum value per day.

```r
generate.supply<-  function(way='',
                            file.name='Supply',
                            days=7,
                            min=100,
                            max=140,
                            goods='Milk, packaging',
                            deliver=NULL){
  
  #creating a table from a single column with a length of days
  tabl<-data.frame('Day'=1:days)
  #use the colnames()function to create a column header
  #adding columns for each product
  for(i in 1:length(goods)){
    tabl[i+1]<-sample(x=min[i]:max[i], size = days)
    colnames(x=tabl)[i+1]=goods[i]
  }
  
  if (!is.null(deliver)) {
    tabl <- as.data.frame((as.matrix(deliver) + as.matrix(tabl) - abs(as.matrix(deliver) - as.matrix(tabl))) / 2)
  }
  
  #write this table to a file with the extension txt
  # write.table(
  #   x=tabl,
  #   file= paste0(way,file.name),
  #   col.names = TRUE,
  #   row.names = FALSE
  # )
  return(tabl)
}
```

The modifies function checks if delivery is provided as input `is.null(deliver)`. If `deliver` is present, it calculates the minimum per good and day, so sales couldn't exeed the deliveries. For this calculation the data.frame is transformed into a matrix and we use `minimum(x,y) = (x + y - | x - y |) / 2`.
But be careful: this works if and only if your data.frame contains numbers.

So for calculation the sales you use the delivery as addtional input which defaults to NULL:

```r
deliver <- generate.supply(way = "", 
                           file.name= 'Shop1_in_K',
                           days=7,goods = c('Cottage cheese, pcs','Kefir, pcs', 'Sour cream, pcs'),
                           min=c(85,100,110),
                           max=c(110,120,130))# generating delivery
sales <- generate.supply(way = "", 
                         file.name= 'Shop1_out_K',
                         days=7,
                         goods = c('Cottage cheese, pcs','Kefir, pcs', 'Sour cream, pcs'),
                         min=c(85,100,110),
                         max=c(105,119,125), 
                         deliver=deliver)# generating sales
```

Comment: Could you,please, explain this expression:  `if (!is.null(deliver)) {
    tabl <- as.data.frame((as.matrix(deliver) + as.matrix(tabl) - abs(as.matrix(deliver) - as.matrix(tabl))) / 2)` with more details?

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong? Can you explain your problem?